# exchange the elements in diagonal in Array - C#

Tags: c#, matrix, diagonal

I'd like to know how to write a program in 2D array to exchange the elements of main diagonal with secondary diagonal then print the result 
like this

**3** 2 7 
4 **5** 3 
2 8 **9**  
 
and the result show like this

**7** 2 3 
4 **5** 3 
9 8 **2**

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: And why do you tag this with c?

Comment: Is the matrix guaranteed to be square?

Comment: @GiladGreen i don't have a clear code that's why i don't post it

Comment: by mistake for c, and yeah I want to be square @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: are you pertinent about 3*3 matrix or it should work for any 2d array?

Comment: yeah it's for 3*3 matrix i just to test first and then try to work with any 2d array

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not a very specific problem, but as I don't see the part where you're stuck I'll try to explain a whole example to you:

```
static int[,] GetDiagonallySwitched(int[,] oldMatrix)
{
    var newMatrix = (int[,])oldMatrix.Clone();

    for (var i = 0; i < oldMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        var invertedI = oldMatrix.GetLength(0) - i - 1;
        newMatrix[i, i] = oldMatrix[i, invertedI];
        newMatrix[i, invertedI] = oldMatrix[i, i];
    }
    return newMatrix;
}
```

First of all I'm cloning the old matrix, because a few values actually remain the same. Then I switch the values from the left side to the right side. I'm doing this with the `invertedI`, which basically is i from the other side - so that in the end the cross is mirrored and it seems as though the lines switched. This is working for any size of the matrix.

For the printing: If you actually want to print it bold, you'll have to use a RTB in WinForms, but I don't guess this was part of your question. Otherwise you could use this code to print the matrix:

```
static void Print(int[,] switched)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < switched.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < switched.GetLength(1); x++)
            Console.Write(switched[y, x]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: What errors do you get? It's very strange because it works fine for me. I hope that your matrix is quadratic?

Comment: i get error in OldMatrix ..and if i type any number it will close

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Could you provide a code example? And what closes? It totally depends on how you implemented my solution. And what exact error are you getting with the OldMatrix?